# View is not updating after getting data from server in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting employee model from API using Ajax and putting that into Employee Model But it's not reflecting on UI same, after you click on Browser 2,3 times it appears on UI.

Component is this:

```
       import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
    import {Router, RouteConfig, RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
    import * as moment from 'moment';
    var Chart = require('../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min');
    var $ = require('../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min');
    var jqui = require('../../node_modules/jquery-ui/datepicker');

    import {DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES, BUTTON_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
    import {employeeFactory} from '../../factory/employeeFactory';


    @Component({
      selector: 'loan_application',
      templateUrl: './app/loan_application/loan_application.html',
      directives: [RouterLink, RouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, BUTTON_DIRECTIVES],
      providers: [employeeFactory]
    })
    export class LoanApplicationComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
      public progress: number;
      private employee: any;
      public constructor(private _router: Router, private routeParam: RouteParams, private _employeeFactory: employeeFactory) {
        this.progress = 1;
        this.progress = this.routeParam.params['state'] ? parseInt(this.routeParam.params['state'].match(/\d+/)[0]) : null;
        this.employee = null;
        this.loading = false;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.charElem = $('#loanChart');
        // this.drawChart(true);

        $(function () {
          $('.txtDate').datepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonText: '<i class="fa fa-calendar" style="font-size:33px;"></i>',
          });
        });
      }

  private getEmployeeProfile() {
        this._employeeFactory.getEmployeeProfile((profile) => {
          if (profile.entity) {
            this.employee = profile.entity;
            console.log('employee', this.employee)

            this.requestloan.customerId = profile.entity.customerId
          }
        }, (err) => {
          if (err.status == 401) {
            this._router.navigate(['OTPEpmloyeeComponent']);
          }
        });
      }
      ngOnInit() {
        this.getEmployeeProfile();
        this.getBankDetails();
      }

    }
```

and template is :

```
<div [class]="selectedSection(1)" id="step-1">
                <div class="row padding-top-bottom-15">

                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">
                        <label class="control-label" for="title">Title <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input id="title" required="required" [(ngModel)]='employee.title' class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label" for="first-name">First Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input id="first-name" required="required" [(ngModel)]='employee.firstName' class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                        <label class="control-label" for="middle-name">Middle Name <span class="required"></span></label>
                        <input id="middle-name" required="required" [(ngModel)]='employee.middleName' class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                        <label class="control-label" for="last-name">Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input id="last-name" required="required" [(ngModel)]='employee.lastName' class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row padding-top-bottom-15">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label" for="first-name">Mobile Number <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        <input id="first-name" required="required" [(ngModel)]='employee.mobNumber' class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label" for="gender">Gender <span class="required">*</span></label><br/>
                        <div class="btn-group" id="gender">
                            <label class="btn {{gender==='Female'?'btn-success':'btn-default'}}" [(ngModel)]='employee.gender' btnRadio="Female" uncheckable>Female</label>
                            <label class="btn {{gender==='Male'?'btn-success':'btn-default'}}" [(ngModel)]='employee.gender' btnRadio="Male" uncheckable>Male</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="row padding-top-bottom-15">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <label class="control-label" for="email-id">Email Id<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='employee.email' id="email-id" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 tDate" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row padding-top-bottom-15">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <label class="control-label" for="DOB"> DOB <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn dob-container">
                                        <input type="text" (change)="checkdate()" [(ngModel)]='employee.dob' id="DOB" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 txtDate" />
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="row padding-top-bottom-15">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <label class="control-label" for="home-address"> Home Address <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                <textarea name="home-address" [(ngModel)]='employee.homeAddress' id="home-address" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What could be the reason delay in UI updation ?
Is this because I am replacing Model and not populating ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the `ChangeDetectorRef` class and its `detectChanges` method:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class LoanApplicationComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef, ...) { // <-------
    (...)
  }

  private getEmployeeProfile() {
    this._employeeFactory.getEmployeeProfile((profile) => {
      if (profile.entity) {
        this.employee = profile.entity;
        console.log('employee', this.employee)

        this.requestloan.customerId = profile.entity.customerId
        this.cdr.detectChanges(); // <-------
      }
    });
```